# Binding the selected item from DataGroup (dataprovider is an XML list) to another component (FLEX 4)

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding, datagrid

Good day to everyone!

I have a DataGroup featuring thumbnails that it gets from XML list passed into an ArrayCollection. I also have a custom item renderer for the datagroup. What I can't make to work is the following: when an thumbnail in the datagroup is clicked the state changed to the page with the information about the projects.

I have the information in the same XML file. I need to bind the source of richtext and several label components to the selected item from the datagroup with a different property of the project from XML list. It it were a simple List component, I would have done it the following way:
**for the list**
    id="myList" dataProvider="{myProjects.Project}" 
**for the label**
    text="{myList.selectedItem.textexample}"

**The code I have for the DataGroup**:

```
<s:DataGroup includeIn="ThumbnailList" dataProvider="{myList}" alpha="0.72" 
blendMode="luminosity" buttonMode="true" id="myThumbs" 
clipAndEnableScrolling="true" height="187" 
itemRenderer="components.CustomRenderer4Thumbs" 
d:userLabel="hos_RepeatedItem" width="320" x="110" y="2" />
```

**The code for the renderer:**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable] public var counter:Number=0;
        protected function image1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(counter==0)
            {
            this.currentState="selected";
            moveIn.play([offsets]);
            counter=1;
            }
            else if(counter==1)
            {
            mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.currentState="DescriptionPagefromThumbs";
            counter=0;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Animate id="Larger"  duration="250">     
        <s:motionPaths>
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="height" valueFrom="50" valueTo="100" />   
            <s:SimpleMotionPath property="width" valueFrom="50" valueTo="100" />    
        </s:motionPaths>
    </s:Animate>
    <s:Animate id="moveIn" target="{offsets}" duration="650">
        <s:SimpleMotionPath property="scaleX" />
        <s:SimpleMotionPath property="scaleY" />
        <s:SimpleMotionPath property="x" />
        <s:SimpleMotionPath property="y" />
    </s:Animate>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="hovered"/>
    <s:State name="selected"/>
</s:states>  
<mx:Image height.hovered="50" click="image1_clickHandler(event)" id="image1" maintainAspectRatio="true" smoothBitmapContent="true" source="{data.Thumb}" d:userLabel="hos_RepeatedItemTH" width.hovered="50" x="0" y="0"/>
```

XML List contains Projects that have at least Title, Thumb, and textexample each.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<s:DataGroup/>` to layout your Thumbs, just go ahead and use `<s:List/>`. You can set the layout of the list component to use `<s:BasicLayout/>`, and set `borderVisible="false"` and `contentBackgroundAlpha="0"` on the `List` so that it looks exactly like the `DataGroup` does, however you will now have access to the `selectedItem` property of the `List`.

For example:

```
<s:List id="myThumbs" includeIn="ThumbnailList" 
        dataProvider="{myList}" 
        borderVisible="false" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
        alpha="0.72" blendMode="luminosity"  
        x="110" y="2" width="320" height="187" 
        itemRenderer="components.CustomRenderer4Thumbs" >
    <s:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout/>
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```